# Fixing the position of the child in relation to the mother

Tags: html, css

I have a mini cart, the counter also shows the number of products added to the shopping cart :

[image]

When the number of products added to the shopping cart is, for example, 1000, The counter tilts to the right :

[image]

I want the counter to be fixed from the right, Rather, it should be pulled from the left side : Like below

[image]

I tried to explain well.

```
<span class="elementor-button-icon-qty" data-counter="1">1</span>
```

```
.elementor-button-icon-qty[data-counter] {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 1.6em;
    height: 1.6em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    top: -.7em;
    inset-inline-end: -.7em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: var(--items-indicator-text-color,#fff);
    background-color: var(--items-indicator-background-color,#d9534f);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px
}
```

Comment: Did you try using the `left` property for positioning?

Comment: Test setting `text-align: end;`

Answer (score 0):

with transform translateX() maybe?

the div is just for example

```css
.elementor-button-icon-qty[data-counter] {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 1.6em;
    height: 1.6em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: var(--items-indicator-text-color,#fff);
    background-color: var(--items-indicator-background-color,#d9534f);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
}
div {
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="elementor-button-icon-qty" data-counter="1">1</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="elementor-button-icon-qty" data-counter="1">10000</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="elementor-button-icon-qty" data-counter="1">1000000000</span>
</div>
```